# How to split a character string into a list values so you can select one of them?

Tags: r, dataframe, strsplit

I have a list of dates, for example "1989-10-09" which are characters and I'm trying to organize them by month. By problem is that these are characters and it's difficult to extract just the month from the dates. Right now I'm trying this:

```
a = as.list(strsplit(official$date[i],split='-'))
```

Where official is the data frame with a date column. But the result is a list of length one, containing "1989" "10" "09" as a single input with no dimensions. The exact result looks like:

```
[[1]]
[1] "1959" "10"   "05"
```

If I try a[2] I get NULL

Comment: It is recommended to convert the date strings into a Date object with the `as.Date()` function, then you could select the extract out the month part with `format(*mydateobject*, "%m")` function.

Comment: Try: `a[[1]][2]`. This is how a list can be subsetted.

Comment: @dave2e thanks, that worked. How would I format out the year? I tried format(*mydateobject*, "%y") and that gave me the last two digits in the year but not all 4.

Comment: For four years use “%Y”.  See help for “strptime “ for the list of all the formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the way you want to go about doing it, you would first need to unlist the item:

```
my_list <- list(1:3)
#>[[1]]
#>[1] 1 2 3

my_list[2]
#> NULL

unlist(my_list)[2]
#>[1] 2
```

Though as @Dave2e mentioned, it might be best to convert it to a date and use more syntactically rich verbs (maybe like `lubridate::month`)